# Why is a 1x1 pytorch convolution changing the data?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am debugging an issue I have using torch::nn:Conv2d.  Here is a simple script which demonstrates the unexpected behavour

```
import torch

use_cuda = torch.cuda.is_available()
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if use_cuda else "cpu")

t = torch.ones([1,1,3,3]).to(device)

print(t)

kernel_size=[1,1]
t2 = torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1,out_channels=1,kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=kernel_size, padding=0).to(device)(t)

print(t2)
```

Running this results in:

```
tensor([[[[1., 1., 1.],
          [1., 1., 1.],
          [1., 1., 1.]]]], device='cuda:0')
tensor([[[[-1.7190, -1.7190, -1.7190],
          [-1.7190, -1.7190, -1.7190],
          [-1.7190, -1.7190, -1.7190]]]], device='cuda:0',
       grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
```

Why is t2 different to t1?  I would expect a 1x1 convolution to leave the input unchanged.

Comment: Does this post help? [the initialization for conv](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-the-default-initialization-of-a-conv2d-layer-and-linear-layer/16055/2)

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question (and answer), were you expecting `t1` to equal `t2`?

Comment: I was, because I was expecting it to give the result of averaging all of the elements in the moving conv "window"

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Michael Szczesny's comment, I replace the conv2d with;

```
t2 = torch.nn.AvgPool2d(1, stride=1)(t)
```

And all is well:

```
tensor([[[[1., 1., 1.],
          [1., 1., 1.],
          [1., 1., 1.]]]], device='cuda:0')
tensor([[[[1., 1., 1.],
          [1., 1., 1.],
          [1., 1., 1.]]]], device='cuda:0')
```

Basically, I was using the wrong function.